# Can't connect to PostgreSQL 12 Server after installation

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

so I tried to connect PostgreSQL 12 Server to to create a database for an online shop that I'm building. When it asks me to "enter the password for the user 'postgres' to connect the server - "PostgreSQL 12" i enter the one i provided during the installation but I'm getting the following error:

i get the following error: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?...

Comment: Your server is either not running, or not accepting TCP/IP connections. It might be only accepting local socket connections via a socket file like `/var/run/something`. We'd need to know how you installed it to help debug.

Comment: when i installed it, im on mac btw, it asked me for port:and the default was 5432 so i just clicked next. But now when i start the app pgAdmin4 it goes to this >http://127.0.0.1:59470/

Comment: Which port the pgadmin4 app server runs on is unrelated to what port the PostgreSQL database server runs on.